# Bind all results automatically

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

If i do a `SELECT * FROM xxx` is there a way to bind all recieved rows automatically?

Since it's not that useful if i do a `*` but need to bind the results manually anyways.

Comment: Why? For example if i receive the rows "test1", "test2" then it should get bindet to $test1 and $test2 like you would do it manually.

Comment: I deleted my comment, because I skipped the exampled SQL Query

Comment: Btw, you are confusing params with results.

Comment: Yeah my bad. Of cours ei mean bind_result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 options.

If you get lucky and your PHP installations supports `get_result()`, you can get it and then use conventional `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` and such.

If not - you have to do some magic out of `result_metadata()`, `call_user_func_array()` and such

Comment: Thanks works fine. Why you said "if you get lucky?" Isn't this method available if mysqli is available?

Comment: it depends, as I said, on PHP installation. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Mysqli+get_result for the evidence

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to bind from a select, this option is also available to you:

```
$Query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM TABLE");
$Query->execute();
$Results = $Query->get_result(); // This little gem here
$Array = $Results->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

Instead of having to use `bind_result` you can just fetch an array automatically